# How is SkekMal (Hunter skeksis) alive?

Tags: dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

SkekMal (Hunter Skeksis) doesn't appear to participate in the crystal draining rituals that the other Skeksis perform in order to sustain their long lives. He also seems to be in better shape than the other Skeksis. How is he able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Skeksis are naturally very long lived.**

[Lisa Hensen herself has said](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/on-demand/2019-08-30/dark-crystal-timeline-explained-netflix/) "the Skeksis are almost immortal."

In the show, the Heretic says they've waited 379 trine (which is a Thra year) to present their surprise. He and Urgo could have only been preparing his surprise after he was banished, and therefore no longer had access to any of the Skeksis' rejuvenating techniques.

The Chamberlain also says to Rian in episode six "Skeksis are to Gelfling as Gelfling are to the crawlies," in terms of lifespan, however, it should be noted that the Chamberlain also had said "Skeksis are immortal," and so he was possibly exaggerating the Skeksis' lifespan and other strengths to justify their treatment of the Gelfling.

[According to the movie's novelization](https://darkcrystal.fandom.com/wiki/Skeksis), the Skeksis are trying to extend their lives so they can live to the next conjunction, which will allow them to achieve true immortality. And so already long lived, and the conjunctions being only one thousand years apart, the Skeksis might only have need to extend their lives a little in order to survive that long. However, it seems *Age of Resistance* might contradict any canon established by the graphic novels, novelization, and so forth, so it is unclear at this point if this is considered truly canon.

As for the particularly good condition of the Hunter, I personally assume it's because while the other Skeksis mostly laze about, he clearly actually conditions his body.

Comment: To add to this answer, [the novelization states](http://lauraknauth.com/moviecollectibles/Smith.html) "The light of the Great Conjunction would irradiate the Skeksis with energy, but a left-handed energy only, darkly colored, rich in malevolence." In other words, the Skeksis seemingly derive their immortality from the Darkening itself. This seems to make them both dependent on it and mutates their bodies in the process.

Answer (score 0):

By the end of season 1, this is not addressed. The same could be asked about Heretic. 
Supposition: Skeksis live a long time but they age. Those in the Crystal Castle are more focussed on looking youthful than simply being alive.